# Using confint in R on dataset with NAs

Tags: r, lme4

For a null model glmer() I would like to calculate 95% CI of the intercept by using the confint() function in R on a dataset that contain NAs. Below is the model summary:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: cbind(df$Valid.detections, df$Missed.detections) ~ 1 + (1 | SUR.ID) +      (1 | Unit)
   Data: df
Control: glmerControl(calc.derivs = F, optCtrl = list(maxfun = 20000))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 21286.9  21305.4 -10640.4  21280.9     3549 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.40089 -0.39994 -0.00010  0.02841  0.56340 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 Unit   (Intercept) 2.237e+01 4.729e+00
 SUR.ID (Intercept) 1.883e-10 1.372e-05
Number of obs: 3552, groups:  Unit, 3552; SUR.ID, 20

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -2.07468    0.08331   -24.9   <2e-16 ***
```

However, when I try to calculate 95% CIs for the intercept it returns an error:

```
Computing bootstrap confidence intervals ...
Error in if (const(t, min(1e-08, mean(t, na.rm = TRUE)/1e+06))) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In bootMer(object, bootFun, nsim = nsim, ...) :
  some bootstrap runs failed (200/200)
Timing stopped at: 42.47 0.289 45.836
```

I googled the error and warning messages for a solution and found this thread http://r-sig-mixed-models.r-project.narkive.com/3vst8TmK/r-sig-me-confint-mermod-method-boot-throws-error, in which Ben Bolker suggested that one way to work around this issue is to remove the rows with NAs prior to using the confint() function. I tried this and no error / warnings are returned, but found that the calculated 95% CIs do not envelope the intercept estimate.

```
> c0
    2.5 %    97.5 % 
-3.129255 -2.931859
```

The calculated CIs do envelope the intercept estimate of the null model of which the NAs were excluded prior the use of the confint() function, however, I need the NAs in there, if possible. Any suggestions how this would be possible?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Any chance you can use the development version of `lme4` which fixes this bug?  See the [README file](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/README.md) for installation instructions ...

Comment: Dear Ben, I'm currently using lme4 1.1-7.

Comment: Yes.  My question was whether you can try 1.1-8 (the development version).

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that there was a newer version. I installed 1.1-8 and indeed, the problem is solved and CIs envelope the intercept estimate. However the following warning is returned: In bootMer(object, FUN = FUN, nsim = nsim, ...) : some bootstrap runs failed (109/300). I looked up this warning and came to a recently revived thread (https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/231). Does this mean we just have to be patient and hopeful for you to solve the underlying issues related to confint() function?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.  If you want a workaround you can use `update()` (as may be shown in that issue ...) Basically, the problem is in `refit()`, which is downstream of `confint()`: `confint() calls `bootMer()` which calls `refit()` ...

Comment: Alright, nothing to do about it now. Thank you for the help though!